# in this paragraph i keep getting errors 'canot resolve symbol (and method) '

Tags: java, android

This is the only problem i have in the whole application.

[image]

Comment: You need to import those classes!

Comment: HttpClient has been deprecated in API 23...use  HttpURLConnection instead..

Comment: Note: don't use an image to show your code, please add the code in the question itself so that it is easy for the search engine to filter this thread.

Answer (score 1):

[**HttpClient was deprecated in API Level 22** and has been **removed** in API Level 23](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). You have to use `URLConnection`.

If you anyway need in API 23, add this to your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

NOTE: Instead, I would recommend using [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
     InputStream irs;
     URL url = new URL("**your URL**");

try{
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(45000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();
    irs = conn.getInputStream();
    }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStactTrace();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

please import those classes.

it may be deprecated 
so please add this to your build file

dependencies {

compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

}